# Error in R that concerns loading of gsl package

Tags: r, function, error-handling, arguments, gsl

this might be a very particular question, but I have this function (see below) which I created and every time I try to run it with normal =FALSE aka using the else statement I get the following error: Loading required namespace: gsl
Failed with error:  ‘there is no package called ‘gsl’’
I do not get the error if normal = TRUE. 
I tried to install the gsl package but was not able to do it. Does one of you know why the error term pops up in the first place?
Thanks for your help!

```
  if(normal==TRUE){
    moments1 <- c(mean=0, variance=var1, skewness=0, kurtosis=3.0)
    moments2 <- c(mean=0+(-es*(sqrt(((sample1-1) *(var1)+(sample2-1)*(var2))/(sample1+sample2-2)))), variance=var2, skewness=0, kurtosis=3.0)
  } else{
    moments1 <- c(mean=0, variance=var1, skewness=0.5, kurtosis=5.0)
    moments2 <- c(mean=0+(-es*(sqrt(((sample1-1) *(var1)+(sample2-1)*(var2))/(sample1+sample2-2)))), variance=var2, skewness=0.5, kurtosis=5.0)
  }
  gen1 <- rpearson(n=sample1, moments=moments1)
  gen2 <- rpearson(n=sample2, moments=moments2)
  Y <- c(gen1, gen2)
  group <- as.factor(c(rep(1, times=length(gen1)), rep(2, times=length(gen2))))
  SimData <- data.frame(Y,group)
  return(SimData)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the code of `rpearson`](https://github.com/cran/PearsonDS/blob/master/R/pearson.r) you can see that this function calls an auxiliary function `rpearson0`, `rpearsonI`, `rpearsonII`, ..., or `rpearsonVII`, depending on the `params` or the `moments` argument.

Now, the [`rpearsonIV`](https://github.com/cran/PearsonDS/blob/master/R/pearsonIV.r) function calls the `gsl::lngamma_complex` function. So in order to use this function, you need the `gsl` package.

Comment: Thank you! Now the function is working without the error. I found a way to install the package and the problem is solved!